# How to have nested GitHub packages on NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've a NPM package repository on GitHub which hosts nested packages (which are depended in through `file:` URL).

When I download it, e.g., when I depend on this GitHub repository `com.qux.nodejs` via `https://github.com/qux/com.qux.nodejs` on another local package `example` in my file system, when I do `npm install` on that local package `example`, the dependency com.qux.nodejs is reported like this:

> npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules\com.qux.nodejs\com.qux.nested" as it does not contain a package.json file.

I want to be able to do:

```js
import { Foo } from 'com.qux.intl';
import { Bar } from 'com.qux.lawHelpers';
```

I'm doing this:

com.qux.nodejs/package.json

```
{
    "name": "com.qux.nodejs",
    "dependencies": {
        "com.qux.nested": "file:./com.qux.nested"
    }
}
```

com.qux.nodejs/com.qux.nested contains a package.json.

I'm relying on com.qux.nodejs like this:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "com.qux.nodejs": "git://github.com/qux/com.qux.nodejs"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't npm install something that isn't a package. NPM install uses the package.json to download and install the different things that a package needs. That is why you're getting this error. NPM doesn't know what do with that line. If the child package has dependencies of its own, and you need to access those dependencies, you're going to have to install them directly in your parent project. Installing a package only gives you access to what that package exports.

Comment: @CharlesDesbiens In this case com.qux exposes com.qux.nested; I've tested and it works; but when com.qux.nested is local to com.qux (not external, like on another GitHub repository) it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So when you `NPM install com.qux` it doesn't work? Or when you git clone the com.qux and then run `NPM install` it doesn't work?

Comment: Is there a package.json file in file:./com.qux.nested?

Comment: Could be a few things, check this example out https://github.com/lcherone/nested_npm/tree/master

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks. Actually I'm relying on the GitHub repository though, and npm reports the nested packages don't have package.json.

Comment: I not sure what you mean, every line you add into in `dependencies` would require a package.json, be it a package on npm, file:// or on github though git:// handler, my example bundles it all into 1 git repo but you dont need to, it could be part of an org and each repo in the org is a package

Comment: it would help if https://github.com/qux/com.qux.nodejs didn't 404

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Here: https://github.com/hydroper/q.x This isn't my project though.

Comment: cool, you would need to inside that main /package.json, add the line "com.q.helpers": "file://q.helpers"` etc which then loads the package inside q.helpers/package.json and then that package.json loads and sub modules.. this is all for if you want `import { helpers } from 'com.q'` etc it entirly depends on how you want to use it

Comment: btw, if your above doesn't export `Foo`, you cant do `import { Foo } from 'com.qux.intl';`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I had put that into dependencies, but it didn't appear on the repo. I just updated it. You can reproduce that after `npm install` it says q.helpers has no package.json. I'm guessing this is a bug though...

Comment: see PR, you have alot missing, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What I was wanting was a NPM monorepo. There's a tool Lerna that allows you to create a monorepo package. It won't auto add the subpackages created by `lerna create com.qux.nested` as dependencies of the NPM monorepo, but that can be done by hand, though.

For more info: https://morioh.com/p/9832b52b1854/

To create a NPM monorepo:

```
$ cd com.qux.nodejs
$ lerna init
```

To create a subpackage:

```
$ lerna create com.qux.nested
```

To publish:

```
$ lerna publish from-git
```